# tfilefetch dynamic post parameters from tmysqlinput

Tags: php, post, talend

In talend, my job is like this:

```
tMysqlInput--->tLogRow--->tFileFetch
```

tLogRow show something like this :

```
param1|valeur1
param2|valeur2
param3|valeur3
....
```

**I'd like to post all these parameters via POST to a php file,**
I tried to do that with tFilFetch but I can't retrieve the parameters.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Does your tMysqlInput have a key-value schema ?

Answer (score 0):

tLogRow shows a key-value schema, so we have to get all parameters in one row before ask tFileFetch to use them,

[image]

tDenormalize settings:

[image]

tFileFetch settings:

[image]